# c++11 variadic template class not compiled

Tags: c++11

```
template <template <class ...args1> class T1, template <class ...args2> class T2>
class CollisionManager
{
public:
   CollisionManager(void);
   ~CollisionManager(void);

   bool checkCollision(T1<args1...> firstArray, T2<args2...> secondArray);
};
```

For some reasons compliler alerts args1 and args2 in `checkCollision()` as **undeclared identifier**

Comment: That's because they *are* undeclared in that scope. `arg1` is scoped to the `<...>` in which it appears. What are you trying to do with `args1` and `args2`? Why can't you just use a standard type template parameter?

Comment: Use a partial specialization if you need to know `T1`, `T2`, `args1` and `args2`

Answer (score 4):

`args1` and `args2` are just placeholders. You can just omit them. Also notice that the parameters to your class template are also *templates*, not types. When `CollisionManager` gets instantiated `args1` and `args2` are not even bound to any types.

**Update**:
It seems to me, that you want to write something like this:

```
template <class T1, class T2> class CollisionManager;

template <template <class...> class T1,
          template <class...> class T2,
          class... args1,
          class... args2>
class CollisionManager<T1<args1...>, T2<args2...>>
{
public:
   CollisionManagerImpl(void);
   ~CollisionManagerImpl(void);

   bool checkCollision(T1<args1...> firstArray, T2<args2...> secondArray);
};
```